# How do you change format of dataset column to date format in R (easiest method)?

Tags: r, date, format, data-analysis, sqldf

Trying to change the format of the column incident_timestamp so I can accurately query the data using sqldf correctly. [Here is the dataset I have for reference.Column #21 is the column I am interested in changing to date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBY1E.png)

Comment: Provide your data using `dput(head(data, 15))`. Copy and paste the results into your question. A picture provides no information about how the date information is currently stored. Also, there is nothing labeled column #21 in your picture. Perhaps it is the column labeled "incident_timestamp"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert `incident_timestamp` from a character to a date/time value you can use `ymd_hms()` from the `lubridate` package:

```r
library(lubridate)

dt <- data.frame(
  incident_timestamp = c(
    "2017/01/04 01:25:00+00", 
    "2017/03/23 13:15:00+00",
    "2017/03/25 13:45:00+00"
  )
)

dt$converted_incident_timestamp <- 
  ymd_hms(dt$incident_timestamp)

dt
```

**Output**:

```
       incident_timestamp converted_incident_timestamp
 1 2017/01/04 01:25:00+00          2017-01-04 01:25:00
 2 2017/03/23 13:15:00+00          2017-03-23 13:15:00
 3 2017/03/25 13:45:00+00          2017-03-25 13:45:00
```

Comment: what if I cant input all of those times manually? there are over 400,000 times. is there a way to format the entire row?